# Top and Bottom Bars are not visible in iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

In the interface builder of iPhone i have selected the top and bottom bars. i can view both the bars in the View window but when i run the application my iPhone simulator is not showing both the bars. do i need to configure any or want to add any coding to make it visible. Kindly suggest me

Comment: You will have to adjust those "Bars" in the IB itself, maybe you are using a navigation bar which is hiding both of them.

Comment: check if you are not hiding these bar from code.. Or have you set these bar in your visible view controller?

Comment: but am not seeing any options like hidden for using that bars any alternate solution is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you added the top bar and bottom bar on the view from interface builder in the following way, or is the bar is added not on the view.

[image]

Comment: Ya,I had added it already it shows in the view window but when i run it its not visible

Comment: Thank you vimal i got that instead of adding that bar i just enabled it alone thats the prob . now got it clear.

Answer (score 0):

in your destination View Controller use this code

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```